# Change text of Description in Image Library

Tags: filters, hooks, media-library

i would like to change or add text to the Media Library Overlay on the right side if you click on an image and can enter a description for the image. At the moment there stands "Description" or "Caption" (German Version installed).

See Image here: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Even if is not very flexible filter you can use the [gettex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) hook.

Only be aware that this filter runs for every string being translated, so can affect performarce if over-used.

To narrow the performance impact you can add it only of admin footer, and remove it just after had use it:

```
add_action('admin_footer', function() {
  add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_caption_text', 99, 3 );
}, 9 );

function change_caption_text( $trans = NULL, $untrans = NULL, $domain = NULL ) {
  if ( $untrans === 'Caption' && $domain === 'default' ) {
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    $trans = __( ':-)', 'your-domain' );
  }
  return $trans;
}
```

Result:

[image: Change "Caption" label using gettext filter]